# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables, if-statement, database-cursor

I have a #temptable with address information in it that is being read using a cursor. The cursor works great. The if statement in the cursor works 100% for the first record in the #table but for the second record it seems to always return false.

The idea of the if statement is to check in the value exists in the address table in the db and then if it does just get the id. If it doesn't then insert the row and get the id. Stand alone the if statement works 100%. The moment I add it into the cursor it breaks. Its almost as if the variables are being over written somehow.

So if the same row is contained in my #table the row still gets inserted twice into the address_table instead of just once. First time the address is inserted if it does not exist, 2nd time the id of the address in the table should be retured

I have taken out the print statements where i do a *convert()* and it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

**This is the stand alone if statement.**

```
DECLARE @COMP_NUM AS VARCHAR(100) = '4'
DECLARE @COMP_NAME AS VARCHAR(100) = 'TAGASTE'
DECLARE @STREET_NUM AS VARCHAR(100) = '150'
DECLARE @STREET_NAME AS VARCHAR(100) = 'WILLSON'
DECLARE @STREET_TYPE AS INT = 1
DECLARE @SUB AS VARCHAR(100) = 'FAIRLANDS'
DECLARE @CITY AS VARCHAR(100) = 'JOHANNESBURG'
DECLARE @HOMEPHONE AS VARCHAR(100) = '0112355566'
DECLARE @EXISTS AS INT
DECLARE @ADD_ID AS INT

SET @EXISTS = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM CARETEAMZ..ADDRESS_BOOK WHERE HOME_PHONE=@HOMEPHONE 
AND COMPLEX_NUMBER = @COMP_NUM
AND COMPLEX_NAME = @COMP_NAME
AND STREET_NUMBER = @STREET_NUM
AND STREET_NAME = @STREET_NAME
AND STREET_TYPE = @STREET_TYPE
AND SUBURB = @SUB
AND CITY = @CITY)
PRINT ('COUNT ROWS: ' + CONVERT(CHAR(6),@EXISTS))

IF (CONVERT(INT,@EXISTS) > 0)               
BEGIN
    PRINT ('RECORD EXISTS')
    SET @ADD_ID = (SELECT ID FROM CARETEAMZ..ADDRESS_BOOK WHERE HOME_PHONE = @HOMEPHONE 
                    AND COMPLEX_NUMBER = @COMP_NUM
                    AND COMPLEX_NAME = @COMP_NAME
                    AND STREET_NUMBER = @STREET_NUM
                    AND STREET_NAME = @STREET_NAME
                    AND STREET_TYPE = @STREET_TYPE
                    AND SUBURB = @SUB
                    AND CITY = @CITY) 
    PRINT ('ADDRESS ID: ' + CONVERT(CHAR(6),@ADD_ID))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT ('RECORD DOES NOT EXIST')
    INSERT INTO CARETEAMZ..ADDRESS_BOOK (HOME_PHONE, COMPLEX_NUMBER, COMPLEX_NAME, STREET_NUMBER, STREET_NAME,STREET_TYPE, SUBURB, CITY)
    VALUES (@HOMEPHONE, @COMP_NUM,@COMP_NAME, @STREET_NUM,@STREET_NAME,@STREET_TYPE,@SUB,@CITY)

    SET @ADD_ID = (SELECT ID FROM CARETEAMZ..ADDRESS_BOOK WHERE HOME_PHONE = @HOMEPHONE 
                    AND COMPLEX_NUMBER = @COMP_NUM
                    AND COMPLEX_NAME = @COMP_NAME
                    AND STREET_NUMBER = @STREET_NUM
                    AND STREET_NAME = @STREET_NAME
                    AND STREET_TYPE = @STREET_TYPE
                    AND SUBURB = @SUB
                    AND CITY = @CITY) 
    PRINT ('ADDRESS ID: ' + CONVERT(char(6),@ADD_ID))
END
```

**This is my full cursor**

```
DECLARE @COMP AS VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @COMP_LENGTH AS INT
DECLARE @COMP_INDEX AS INT
DECLARE @COMP_NUM AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @COMP_NAME AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @STREET AS VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @STREET_LENGTH AS INT
DECLARE @STREET_INDEX AS INT
DECLARE @STREET_NUM AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @STREET_NAME AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @STREET_VALUE AS VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @STREET_TYPE AS INT
DECLARE @SUB AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CITY AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @HOMEPHONE AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @CITY = 'JOHANNESBURG'

DECLARE ADD_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT [HOME],[COMPLEX], [STREET] FROM #TEMPADD
OPEN ADD_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM ADD_CURSOR INTO @HOMEPHONE,@COMP,@STREET;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
        BEGIN
            --COMPLEX DETAILS
            PRINT('-- COMPLEX DETAILS --')
            PRINT(@COMP) 
            SET @COMP_INDEX = CHARINDEX(',',@COMP)
            PRINT(@COMP_INDEX)
            IF (@COMP_INDEX > 0)
            BEGIN
                    PRINT('COMPLEX TRUE')
                    SET @COMP_NUM = LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(@COMP,0,@COMP_INDEX))))
                    SET @COMP_NAME = LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(@COMP,@COMP_INDEX+1,LEN(@COMP)))))                  
            END
            ELSE 
            BEGIN 
                    PRINT('COMPLEX FALSE')
                    SET @COMP_NUM = NULL
                    SET @COMP_NAME = NULL
            END
            PRINT('COMPLEX NUMBER: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@COMP_NUM))
            PRINT('COMPLEX NAME: ' + @COMP_NAME)

            -- STREET ADDRESS
            PRINT('-- STREET NAME --')
            PRINT(@STREET) 
            SET @STREET_INDEX = CHARINDEX(',',@STREET)
            PRINT(@STREET_INDEX)
            IF (@STREET_INDEX > 0)
            BEGIN
                    PRINT('STREET TRUE')
                    SET @STREET_NUM = LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(@STREET,0,@STREET_INDEX))))
                    SET @STREET = (SUBSTRING(@STREET,@STREET_INDEX+1,LEN(@STREET)))
                    PRINT(@STREET)
                    SET @STREET_INDEX = CHARINDEX(',',@STREET)
                    SET @STREET_NAME = LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(@STREET,0,CHARINDEX(' ',@STREET)))))
                    SET @SUB = LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(@STREET,@STREET_INDEX+1,LEN(@STREET)))))
                    SET @STREET_VALUE = SUBSTRING(@STREET,0,CHARINDEX(',',@STREET))
                    SET @STREET_TYPE = (SELECT ID FROM CARETEAMZ..STREET_TYPE WHERE STREET_TYPE = RTRIM(LTRIM((SUBSTRING(@STREET_VALUE,LEN(@STREET_VALUE)-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@STREET_VALUE))+2,LEN(@STREET_VALUE)-CHARINDEX(',',@STREET_VALUE))))))                  
            END
            ELSE 
            BEGIN 
                    PRINT('STREET FALSE')
                    SET @STREET_NUM = NULL
                    SET @STREET_NAME = NULL
                    SET @STREET_TYPE = NULL
                    SET @SUB = NULL
            END
            PRINT('STREET NUMBER: ' + @STREET_NUM)
            PRINT('STREET NAME: ' + @STREET_NAME)
            PRINT('STREET TYPE: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@STREET_TYPE))
            PRINT('SUBURB: ' + @SUB)

            --CHECK IF THE ADDRESS / PHONE NUMBER ALREADY EXISTS IN THE DB
            DECLARE @ADD_ID AS INT
            DECLARE @EXISTS AS INT

            SET @EXISTS = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM CARETEAMZ..ADDRESS_BOOK WHERE HOME_PHONE = @HOMEPHONE 
            AND COMPLEX_NUMBER = @COMP_NUM
            AND COMPLEX_NAME = @COMP_NAME
            AND STREET_NUMBER = @STREET_NUM
            AND STREET_NAME = @STREET_NAME
            AND STREET_TYPE = @STREET_TYPE
            AND SUBURB = @SUB
            AND CITY = @CITY)
            PRINT ('COUNT ROWS: ' + CONVERT(CHAR(6),@EXISTS))
            IF (@EXISTS > 0)                
            BEGIN
                PRINT ('RECORD EXISTS')
                SET @ADD_ID = (SELECT ID FROM CARETEAMZ..ADDRESS_BOOK WHERE HOME_PHONE = @HOMEPHONE 
                                AND COMPLEX_NUMBER = @COMP_NUM
                                AND COMPLEX_NAME = @COMP_NAME
                                AND STREET_NUMBER = @STREET_NUM
                                AND STREET_NAME = @STREET_NAME
                                AND STREET_TYPE = @STREET_TYPE
                                AND SUBURB = @SUB
                                AND CITY = @CITY)

                PRINT ('ADDRESS ID: ' + CONVERT(CHAR(6),@ADD_ID))
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                PRINT ('RECORD DOES NOT EXIST')
                INSERT INTO CARETEAMZ..ADDRESS_BOOK (HOME_PHONE, COMPLEX_NUMBER, COMPLEX_NAME, STREET_NUMBER, STREET_NAME,STREET_TYPE, SUBURB, CITY)
                VALUES (@HOMEPHONE, @COMP_NUM,@COMP_NAME, @STREET_NUM,@STREET_NAME,@STREET_TYPE,@SUB,@CITY)

                SET @ADD_ID = (SELECT ID FROM CARETEAMZ..ADDRESS_BOOK WHERE HOME_PHONE = @HOMEPHONE 
                                AND COMPLEX_NUMBER = @COMP_NUM
                                AND COMPLEX_NAME = @COMP_NAME
                                AND STREET_NUMBER = @STREET_NUM
                                AND STREET_NAME = @STREET_NAME
                                AND STREET_TYPE = @STREET_TYPE
                                AND SUBURB = @SUB
                                AND CITY = @CITY) 

                PRINT ('ADDRESS ID: ' + CONVERT(char(6),@ADD_ID))

            END

            --FETCH NEXT
            FETCH NEXT FROM ADD_CURSOR INTO @HOMEPHONE,@COMP, @STREET;
        END
CLOSE ADD_CURSOR;
DEALLOCATE ADD_CURSOR;
```

Ok so i've look at both @HLGEM & @kuru kuru pa's answers. @HLGEM This is just a small part of a bigger cursor and unfortunately MERGER SQL won't work for my current needs. I'm not to worried about performance as this is just to import data into my db.

@kuru kuru pa's answer is a good one but unfortunately i still seem to be getting the same issue again. 1st time i run the cursor it runs 100%. Inserts all the values, 2nd time it should only return IDs but id doesn't return anything and inserts the duplicates.

Below are the 2 table create statements with some dummy data.

**TEMP TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPADD
(
    HOME VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    COMPLEX VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    STREET VARCHAR(100) NULL,
)

INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES ('011 679 6787',  '32,Tagaste',   '150,Willson Street, Land')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES ('011 679 1909',  NULL,   '29,Bunkara Street, Rio')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES ('011 689 2630',  NULL,   '275,Kings Lynne Road, Glen')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES (NULL,    NULL,   '275,Kings Lynne Road, Glen')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES ('011 799 5917',  '5,The Vineyard',   '45,Hilary Road, Ridge')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES (NULL,    '5,The Vineyard',   '45,Hilary Road, Ridge')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES ('011 679 5857',  NULL,   '11A,Alexandra Street, Florida')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES ('011 679 5857',  NULL,   '11A,Alexandra Street, Florida')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES ('011 679 3225',  NULL,   '752, Without Avenue, Weltevreden')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES ('011 679 8909',  NULL,   '18,Smit Street,Land')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES ('011 679 8909',  '512,Athenian View',    '158,Smit Street, Fairland')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES (NULL,    '741,Eagle Trace Landing',  'Eagle Canyon Golf Estate, Honey')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES (NULL,    '741,Eagle Trace Landing',  'Eagle Canyon Golf Estate, Honey')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES (NULL,    '741,Eagle Trace Landing',  'Eagle Canyon Golf Estate, Honey')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES (NULL,    '741,Eagle Trace Landing',  'Eagle Canyon Golf Estate, Honey')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES (NULL,    '741,Eagle Trace Landing',  'Eagle Canyon Golf Estate, Honey')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES (NULL,    '741,Eagle Trace Landing',  'Eagle Canyon Golf Estate, Honey')
INSERT INTO #TEMPADD (HOME,COMPLEX,STREET) VALUES (NULL,    NULL,   '106A,3rd Avenue, Land')
```

**ADDRESS TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ADDRESS_BOOK](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PoBox] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Complex_Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Complex_Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Street_Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Street_Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Street_Type] [int] NULL,
    [Suburb] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Home_Phone] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: To be honest I'd be much more tempted to look at this had you included some `create table` scripts so I could just run it. I don't see why you are converting `@Exists` to `int` when it is an `int`?

Comment: I have posted the code for you to create tables... Thank you for your help so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a lot of code to read through...

First observation (not an answer to your question, but FWIW) is that you might be using the wrong tool for the job.  Not sure a cursor is necessary here.  Anyway...

Just spot-checking for now...(unless you want to add the create table script @martin suggested...(i'll give you a more thorough answer if you do)

Your use of @Exists is redundant.  Basically, you're using @Exists to tell you if @Add_ID will exist.  It's an indirect / redundant approach.

```
If @Exists exists, then @Add_ID exists.
```

You can use a much more boring tautology (direct approach):

```
If @Add_ID exists, then @Add_ID exists.
```

So your code could be this:

<s>`SET @Exists = ...`</s>
<s>`If @Exits > 0...`</s>

```
SET @ADD_ID = (SELECT ID FROM CARETEAMZ..ADDRESS_BOOK WHERE HOME_PHONE = @HOMEPHONE AND ...)
IF @ADD_ID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   PRINT(...)
END
ELSE...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth would you use a cursor to do this? Suggest you read this article to see how much easier (as well as faster) it is to do using set-based techniques:

http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: Great site by the way.. unfortunately merge sql isn't going to solve my problem... this cursor is just a small part of the bigger picture... Not to worried bout performance either as it is only going to be run once to populate a blank db... I have posted the code for  the tables the cursor runs on...